# Is there a FIXED function in QuickSight like Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, amazon-quicksight

I’m trying to manipulate a Tableau function to QS. My output is not getting the same number, so I am doing something wrong here. Can anyone help with this?

Tableau - { FIXED [marketplace_id],[monthending],[page_type],[device_type]:MAX([traffic_o])}

QS - maxOver(traffic_o,[{marketplace_id},monthending,{page_type},{device_type}],PRE_AGG)

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying any visualization filters?

In Tableau, the FIXED() function gets evaluated before the visualization filters. In QuickSight, your LOD expressions can be executed before or after the filters. If you want to replicate the FIXED() function in QuickSight, you should use the PRE_FILTER parameter in you LOD Expression.

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_filters.htm
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/level-aware-calculations.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **Level-Aware-Calculations**.
They work exactly like the FIXED() function in Tableau, however they are actually built into the aggregation functions themselves.

Using your example, the corresponding QuickSight custom field would be as simple as:

```
MAX({traffic_o}, [{marketplace_id},{monthending},{page_type},{device_type}])
```

Note: The group by clause will need to be in list format even if it is just 1 field (use brackets).

Here is the official documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/level-aware-calculations.html